# How do you "pin" a flash error message in the CP?

Tags: plugin-development, error-message

It's possible to generate a "flash" error message at the top of the control panel like this:

```php
craft()->userSession->setError('Your custom plugin error message.');
```

The message appears at the top of the control panel when the page loads, but then fades away after a few seconds. **Is there any way to "pin" the message to the top of the page, so it stays indefinitely?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried but you could probably use the CP Custom JavaScript plugin to force display of `.notification.error` as the flash only sets `display: none;` and does not remove the element.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks Shane! I'll give that a whirl and let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. The CP’s Javascript will automatically hide all flash messages 2 or 4 seconds after page load (4 if it’s an error).

Comment: Fair enough, thanks Brandon. Maybe I'll submit it as an official feature request. ;)